# Unable to update Podfile for AFAmazonS3Client please fix

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, github, cocoapods

i am trying to update my pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, "6.0"

target "Papp" do

# Frameworks
pod 'Parse-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.2.19'
pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.0.4'
pod 'CrashlyticsFramework', '~> 2.2.1'

#Pods
#pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.2.3'
pod 'IDMAlertViewManager', '~> 1.1'
#pod 'FXBlurView', '~> 1.6.1'
#pod 'GPUImage', '~> 0.1.4'
pod 'DACircularProgress', '~> 2.2'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.0'
#pod 'DAKeyboardControl', '~> 2.3.1'
#pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.2.3'
pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.2'

pod 'RDRStickyKeyboardView', :git => 'git@github.com:fjcaetano/RDRStickyKeyboardView.git', :branch => 'no_init'
#pod 'RDRStickyKeyboardView', :path => '/Users/flaviocaetano/github/RDRStickyKeyboardView'

#pod 'AFAmazonS3Client', :path => '/Users/flaviocaetano/github/AFAmazonS3Client'
pod 'AFAmazonS3Client', :git => 'git@github.com:fjcaetano/AFAmazonS3Client.git'

pod 'FXForms', :git => 'git@github.com:fjcaetano/FXForms.git'
#pod 'FXForms', :path => '/Users/flaviocaetano/github/FXForms'

pod 'BlurryModalSegue', :git => 'git@github.com:fjcaetano/BlurryModalSegue.git'
#pod 'BlurryModalSegue', :path => '/Users/flaviocaetano/github/BlurryModalSegue'

inhibit_all_warnings!

end

target "PappTests" do

end
```

**I got following error**

```
my-MacBook-Air:pappiosmaster iphonemaclover$ pod install
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `AFAmazonS3Client` from `git@github.com:fjcaetano/AFAmazonS3Client.git`
[!] /usr/bin/git clone git@github.com:fjcaetano/AFAmazonS3Client.git /Users/seemtech/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/f4b1b84822c913fd86bbbfcacbb0e339645fc475 --mirror

Cloning into bare repository '/Users/iphonemaclover/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/f4b1b84822c913fd86bbbfcacbb0e339645fc475'...

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.



Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists.

my-MacBook-Air:pappiosmaster iphonemaclover$
```

**How to fix this i check the https://github.com/fjcaetano/AFAmazonS3Client its public besides that i got this above error.**

**Also want to know how Podfile.lock is created???**

Please check Output of command

its shows following output

```
MacBook-Air:pappiosmaster seemtech$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.131] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/seemtech/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/seemtech/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/seemtech/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/seemtech/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/seemtech/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/seemtech/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/seemtech/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Did you check the original repository url https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client ?

Comment: i am new in pod, can you mention me where i have to make change for it in my pod file?

Comment: changing this 
pod 'AFAmazonS3Client', :git => 'git@github.com:AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client.git'
#pod 'AFAmazonS3Client', :path => '/Users/AFNetworking/github/AFAmazonS3Client'
not working

Answer (score 1):

Try to link pod (**AFAmazonS3Client**) from original repository: Look at screenshot: http://monosnap.com/image/ssRSVml5bh5pwO8rhA4T7hICCsT1De
Then, try to update system gems:

```
gem update --system
```

then, reinstall cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: i already run above command
devs-MacBook-Air:pappiosmaster seemtech$ gem update --system
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.

Comment: also please tell me about how to create podfile.lock

Comment: podfile.lock is created itself, after you run command: pod install in project directory, where Podfile file is located.

Comment: Can you run this comman: `ssh -vT git@github.com`, it seems you have problems with your public/private keys in your system. In trace logs try to find something like this: `debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/almasadilbek/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct`

Comment: please check i add its output

Comment: Seems like problem is not there. I think you should uninstall cocoapods and install it again. Make sure you don't use `sudo` while you install cocoapods again. To uninstall cocoapods follow instructions here: http://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine. To install it again just use `gem install cocoapods`